# LINQ: Link 1:M Table and Merge Results

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have

1. `table Users` (with User.Id and
   such)
2. `table Visibility` (User1Id and User2Id, both are foreign keys to the Users table)
3. `table Contact` (User.Id with foreign key linking 1:1 Contact to User).

The visibility table shall allow users to view *other* user's contacts as well as their own. For that purpose, User1 is allowed to see User2's contacts (but not vice versa).

Now, I'm trying to query like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

`Contact.Where(c => c.UserId == userId || c.UserId IN c.User.Visibilities)` - essentially what I'm trying to do is to return 1. all Contacts records that have the supplied UserId (that's simple and works already of course) *and* to return all Contacts thats associated with a different user, but the user supplied is linked to that different user via User1 : User2 in the Visibility table.

To get a full example going:

```
Users
=====
UserId     Name
10         John
15         Sasha
20         Marcus

Visibility
==========
User1Id    User2Id
10         20

Contact
=======
ContactId  UserId  Zip
1          10      23232
2          15      55555
3          20      92929
```

What I'd like return from the LINQ query when querying for UserID 10 are Contacts `1` and `3` based on the fact that user `10` can already see Contact `1`, and due to the `Visibility` table can also see user `20`'s Contact `3`.

```
Result (when querying for user 10)
======
ContactId  UserId  Zip
1          10      23232
3          20      92929
```

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
Contact.Where(c=>c.UserId == userId || c.User.Visibilities.Any(v=>v.User1Id == userId))
```

Comment: the Visibilities must be mapped on User2Id FK